# Android Croperino - Crop in copy instead of original

Tags: java, android, file

I'm using Croperino with Android to pick a picture from the gallery and then run a crop.

But, when the crop is done the original file is modified and I don't want that, I only need the cropped image inside my app.

I have the following code:

```
CroperinoFileUtil.newGalleryFile(data, getActivity());
Croperino.runCropImage(CroperinoFileUtil.getmFileTemp(), getActivity(), true, 1, 1, 0, 0);
```

I also tried:

```
 File dest = new File(CroperinoFileUtil.getPath(getActivity(), data.getData()), "IMG_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

                try {
                    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(CroperinoFileUtil.getmFileTemp());
                    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                    FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
                    FileChannel outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
                    inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
                    inStream.close();
                    outStream.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

After CroperinoFileUtils.newGalleryFile... and before Croperino.runCropImage...

Anybody know how to do that?

Comment: Hey I am also facing this issue. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That problem made me download the source code and inspect the error

The solution is very easy but as I said it made me download the source code then integrate it with my project

in CropImage.java: find

```
mSaveUri = getImageUri(mImagePath);
```

and replace it with

```
mSaveUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(CroperinoConfig.getsRawDirectory()+CroperinoConfig.getsImageName()));
```

That's all